# .Net exe to migrate DB2 tables into CSV files

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, csv, db2

Trying to extract DB2 tables locally into CSV files so I can later import those CSVs into SQL Server. This is the code I'm working with so far and it keeps blowing up. Any suggestions?

```
        try
        {
            da_local.Fill(td);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception: {0}", e.Message);
        }

        DQELibraries.ImportExport.ExportDatasetToCsvFile(td, @"c:\Temp\");
        Console.WriteLine("Exported File Successfully");

    }
    #region "Environment Detection"
    public static String CurrentEnvironment()
    {
        //DQELibraries.Configuration.GetCurrentEnvironment("DB2");
        String EnvironmentOverride = "DB2";

        if (EnvironmentOverride == "")
        {
            return DQELibraries.Configuration.GetCurrentEnvironment("");
        }
        else
        {
            return DQELibraries.Configuration.GetCurrentEnvironment("DB2");
        }   
    }
    #endregion
}
```

}

Comment: Error messages always help.... one thing I noticed is that you are passing a directory name "c:\temp\". I am not 100% certain but I think you are supposed to be passing a file name.

Comment: Apologies, this is the error message I keep getting: Loaded 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.

Answer (score 2):

You may not need to write your own program for this. DB2 CLP already has utilities for this - please have a look at `EXPORT`.

For example:

```
db2 "EXPORT TO staff.csv OF DEL MODIFIED BY NOCHARDEL SELECT * FROM staff"
```

HTH.

Comment: It's also likely to be far faster than a naively implemented app, especially in a managed language.  Keep in mind that SQL Server has a corresponding load utility, too!